# ¿Como utilizar variables de js en un ts de angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

Buen día.

Lo que necesito sabes es ¿Cómo puedo acceder al valor de la variable ejemplo que está en index.html para usarlo en button-bar.component.ts?

En este ejemplo tengo una variable y un método que le asigna un valor en index.html pero quiero llamar a un método dentro de button-bar.component.ts el cual lo que hará es imprimir el mensaje en la consola del navegador. Tengo el siguiente código de ejemplo.

En la aplicación real estoy usando la siguiente librebría

```
<script src="https://static.vidyo.io/4.1.8.1/javascript/VidyoClient/VidyoClient.js?onload=onVidyoClientLoaded"></script>
```

La librería anterior carga un callback llamado onVidyoClientLoaded como parámetro y despues de que la librería cargue es llamado el callback.

Gracias.

//index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Ejemplo</title>
    <base href="/">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  </head>
  <body>
    <app-root></app-root>
    <script>

      let ejemplo;

      ejemploF();

      function ejemploF() {
        ejemplo = "Hola mundo";
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

//button-bar.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
declare var ejemplo:any;


@Component({
  selector: 'app-button-bar',
  templateUrl: './button-bar.component.html'
})
export class ButtonBarComponent {

  constructor() {
    this.getEjemploFValue(); 
  }

  getEjemploFValue() {
    console.log(ejemplo);
  }
}
```

Comment: Creo que estás planteando mal el funcionamiento de Angular, utilizando sus componentes no es necesario utilizar JavaScript en la vista. Deberías trasladar ese código al componente y ejecutarlo desde allí

Comment: Mira si puedes usar la libreria especifica de Vidyo para Angular
https://github.com/Vidyo/vidyo.io-groupchat-angular

Answer (score 0):

```js
// SERVICIO
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class EjemploService {

  variableDelServicio: any;
}

// COMPONENTE
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { EjemploService } from 'src/app/services/ejemplo.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-ejemplo',
  templateUrl: './ejemplo.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./ejemplo.component.css']
})
export class EjemploComponent implements OnInit {

  variableDelComponente: any;

  constructor( public: miServicio: EjemploService ) { 
    // Accedes a la variable así:
    this.variableDelComponente = miServicio.variableDelServicio;
  }
}
```